# Javascript declare a global variable within AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, post

After sending an Ajax post request, I get an array as a response. I want to use this array in another function, I tried to declare the variable before setting its value without putting it in any function.

```
var their_Info = [];
    $.ajax({
            url: "My PHP url",
            type: "post",
            data: {username:usernames} ,
            success: function (response) {
               their_Info = JSON.parse(response);
            });
```

If I want to use their_Info in a separate function I am getting undefined..

Below is the php script for reference:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$usernames = $_POST['username']; 
//$ids = join("','",$usernames); 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "vKukRKWZRE", "table");
$acc_Info = array();
foreach ($usernames as $value) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$value'";
    $show = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show)) {
        array_push($acc_Info, explode(',', $row['wear']));
    }
}
echo json_encode($acc_Info);
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: you have a missing closing parenthesis in your first code

Comment: Where (and when) are you trying to access `their_Info`?

Comment: Also, ***please*** use prepared statements for this.  You wouldn't want me to try to login as `'; DROP TABLE users; -- `, would ya?

Comment: Ok after reading the possible duplicate I am thinking of calling the functions that uses the variable right after changing their_Info value in the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use `their_Info` before the AJAX completes, it will obviously return `undefined` because AJAX is async.

**The possible solution**

Call your function inside `success` with the data as an argument. By this, you will be using the response only after the AJAX completes

Answer (score 0):

Despite the comment for proper way of handling callback, you can use `window.their_info` to set `their_info` variable in global scope. Not really recommended though.